# C# wait timeout before calling method and reset timer on consecutive calls

Tags: c#, timer, timeout, intervals

I have a event in my code that can possibly get fired multiple times a second at some moment.

However I would like to implement a way to make that method wait 500ms before really firing, if the method gets called again before those 500ms are over, reset the timer and wait for 500ms again.

Coming from javascript I know this is possible with setTimeout or setInterval. However I'm having trouble figuring out how I could implement such a thing in C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `System.Timers.Timer` wrapped in a class to get the behaviour you need:

```
public class DelayedMethodCaller
{
    int _delay;
    Timer _timer = new Timer();

    public DelayedMethodCaller(int delay)
    {
        _delay = delay;
    }

    public void CallMethod(Action action)
    {
        if (!_timer.Enabled)
        {
            _timer = new Timer(_delay)
            {
                AutoReset = false
            };
            _timer.Elapsed += (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) =>
                {
                    action();
                };
            _timer.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            _timer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

This can then be used in the following manner:

```
public class Program
{
    static void HelloWorld(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World! " + i);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DelayedMethodCaller methodCaller = new DelayedMethodCaller(500);
        methodCaller.CallMethod(() => HelloWorld(123));
        methodCaller.CallMethod(() => HelloWorld(123));
        while (true)
            ;
    }
}
```

If you run the example, you will note that "Hello World! 123" is only displayed once - the second call simply resets the timer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reset the timer when the method is called again, consider looking at the ManualResetEvent class:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx

You can use this to notify one or more waiting threads that an event has occurred.

Comment: Interesting. Will dig in

Answer (score -1):

You can use Thread.Sleep() with locking

```
private object locking = new object();

lock (locking )
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    //Your code to run here
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How could i stop this thread from executing if the same method is fired again ?

Comment: Updated answer. Use locking with sleep.

Comment: Not sure if my question was too vague or if I miss something. But this would prevent other calls from firing this code right ? What I'm looking for is to reset the timer to 0 if the method is called again. (So ignore previous calls)

Comment: The lock will stop any other thread from running the code within the lock until the lock is release. So once the lock is released another thread can enter, where the thread will sleep again for 500 ms. So no need to reset the 'timer' to 0 again. So in essence the calls are queued up, when you say reset the timer you mean any calls whilst the thread is locked to disregard them?

Comment: Handy thing but not really what I am looking for. Will update my question.

Answer (score -1):

Just writen super simple class with System.Threading.Thread; With a little different approach Usage.

```
var delayedCaller = new DelayedTimeout(() => HelloWorld(123), 500, false);
delayedCaller.ResetTimer();
delayedCaller.ResetTimer();
```

Currently, you can do it very simple with the following class

```
public class DelayedTimeout
{
    readonly Timer _timer;
    readonly int _timeoutMs;

    public DelayedTimeout(TimerCallback callback, int timeoutMs, bool startNow)
    {
        _timeoutMs = timeoutMs;
        // Should we start now
        var currentTimeoutMs = startNow ? _timeoutMs : Timeout.Infinite;
        _timer = new Timer(callback, null, currentTimeoutMs, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    // Constructor overloading
    public DelayedTimeout(Action callback, int timeoutMs, bool startNow) :
        this(delegate (object? obj) { callback.Invoke(); }, timeoutMs, startNow)
    {}

    public void ResetTimer()
    {
        _timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite); // Stop the timer
        _timer.Change(_timeoutMs, Timeout.Infinite); // Stop the timer
    }
}
```